# How do I keep a part of the pattern matched and use it to replace on BSD sed?

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I have found a soultion for GNU sed, and I also found something like `\1`, but the Terminal tells me it's "not defined in RE".

But what I want to do is this:

If I have a string that looks like this `sinder-city1.gif`, I want to make that `sinder-city.gif`, now I can't just straight up replace the entire string, because I will do this to many different strings, nor can I just remove all numbers before .gif or some other pattern because if there is

```
sinder-city2.gif
sinder-city3.gif
```

I want them to stay intact.

I don't want to replace that. For matching that, I type `sed 's,[a-z]1.gif,` but if I remove that, I will be left with `sinder-cit.gif`. How do I match that `y`?

I want to do like this:

```
sed 's,[a-z]1.gif,[here is the last letter].gif,g'
```

It has to work on BSD sed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
sed 's,\([a-z]\)1\.gif$,\1.gif,g'
```

or, if you want to allow any non-digit before the `1`

```
sed 's,\([^0-9]\)1\.gif$,\1.gif,g'
```

The backslash-parenthesis construct delimits a capture group, which the [FreeBSD man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=re_format&sektion=7) calls a “bracket expression” (despite the use of parentheses — square brackets mean something else). Note that sed uses basic regular expressions (BRE), not extended regular expressions (ERE); the man page describes ERE, and the last paragraph explains the difference between BRE syntax and ERE syntax. I find the [POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03_06) more readable than the BSD man page here; it calls capture groups *back-reference expressions*. The [GNU sed manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Regular-Expressions) is more readable than either; just avoid the features described as GNU extensions.

Given a capture group (a.k.a. back-reference expression), you can use backslash+digit in the replacement text to mean “the text matched by the corresponding capture group”. For example, `\1` in the replacement text is replaced by the text matched by the first capture group in the regular expression. Here there's a single capture group, which captures the letter before `1.gif`.

I changed `1.gif` to `1\.gif` to match the dot literally, and added a trailing `$` to match only at the end of the line.

To give another example of capture groups, if you wanted to operate on arbitrary extensions, you could use something like

```
sed 's,\([^0-9]\)1\(\.[^./]*\)$,\1\2,g'
```